# Fighter cover during Death Star trench run

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

During the attack on the first Death Star, various groups of rebel fighters enter the meridian trench (first Y-wings, then X-wings) in order to get to the (in)famous exhaust port. They enter in groups of three, but because the trench is narrow they could only fly in formation. Vader and his wing man then easily pick them off.

Since only one fighter could attack the exhaust port simultaneously (a small target, only one or two are torpedoes needed), **wouldn't be better for another two fighters to get out of trench and attack Vader and his wing man directly** in order to force them to break off their pursuit of the group leader who could then launch torpedoes without constantly looking back ? Anti-aircraft fire cannot be the reason, because it is almost the same inside the trench, and low above the surface .

Looks like only Han Solo understands this simple tactics, as he easily gets on the Tie Fighters tails and then blasts them, saving Luke

Comment: when the Y-Wings were making their run, is there any evidence the X-Wings even knew the TIES were in the trench? By the the time of the second run, Luke indeed said his group would cover for them, but apparently didn't get the chance. At that point, Luke, Wedge, and Biggs started their run, at which time they were they only fighters left

Comment: @NKCampbell 6:36 in the video, "Guns, they stopped"  and 7:19, "They came from behind !". Each group communicated with base, so they were aware what is going on.  Anyway, my question is not why X-wings didn't cover Y-wings (they were probably too far away) . My question is why Y-wings and X-wings from SAME group didn't cover their leader while he makes trench run, instead of just stupidly flying straight and level in the trench .

Comment: At 10:10 Wedge says to Luke "we'll stay back far enough to cover you", so the X-wings had some plan to protect their leader. I suppose they also had to be in position from which they could replace the leader if the tower guns destroy the leader too.

Comment: Not to answer the question, but they were in the Meridian trench not the equatorial trench.

Comment: Since the fighters are most vulnerable to attack from behind it makes sense to me that the wingmen are literally providing cover by blocking a direct attack to the rear. Yes, they could fly out of the trench and attempt to attack the enemy fighters following them, but that would leave the lead fighter completely exposed to a direct attack from behind. Remember that the mission is to ensure that the lead fighter gets through and drops the bombs in the exhaust port. Everyone else is expendable.

Comment: @Josafoot You are right, will edit that .

Comment: @Nathan It doesn't make sense because it doesn't slow  down Vader's group. They just overtake one fighter at the time and blast them . Tie Fighters do not need to slow down or change course . If Rebel fighters did turn and attack, Tie fighters would need to change course (and loose time) or get destroyed themselves . SW is based on WW2 , and in WW2 escorts didn't fly straight and level, they attempted to shoot down attacking fighters while bombers proceeded to target .

Comment: you're looking for logic in all the wrong places. It's space fantasy - not a war simulator

Comment: You're a rebel pilot in formation with your leader, Luke Skywalker. You enter the trench. You become aware, for whatever reason, that Vader and his goons are entering the trench. Now what? You and your other wingman exit the trench. Vader's goons also exit the trench to deal with you. Congratulations, you have now left Luke own his own with Darth Vader right behind him, with no way to defend himself. Luke gets shot down, the Death Star isn't destroyed, the galaxy is doomed.

Comment: Han had the all-important element of surprise.

Comment: @rs.29 Star Wars is based on World War 2??? LOL

Comment: @DisturbedNeo You are Y-wing pilot, you follow your leader. Tie fighters enter trench. You exit the trench and go straight for them . Since Y-wings have shields, and Ties don't (except for Vader), they would have to break off . If some Ties remain on same course, they would get shoot. Either way, you break their formation and give leader some time for clear run on exhaust port. Not to mention, you increase chances of other two groups ( X-wings) . Very simple - you don't loose 7 fighters to 3 like in the movie .

Comment: Did the Y-Wings in the film have shields? I know the Fantasy Flight Games X-Wing game Y-Wings have them ;) but those Y-Wings in the film were shot to pieces fairly quickly with no indication of shields. Your scenario still falls apart because even if Vader's wingmen peel off to track the Y-Wing wingmen, Vader still stays on the leader and obliterates him in the trench

Comment: "You are Y-wing pilot, you follow your leader. Tie fighters enter trench. You exit the trench and..." leave the leader alone and uncovered against three TIE fighters while you pull up and loop around to catch the TIES from behind. Also - the TIES far outpace your speed so you are left in the dust and now exposed to the laser cannon battery that can now resume firing because the TIES are no longer in the trench having left after blasting the leader.

Comment: @NKCampbell Fighter cover does not mean "we stay close to you, so we could all die together" . Fighter cover means "we attack your enemies so they don't have time to attack you" . This is how it works in real world, especially in WW2, and SW is based on it.  Y-wings had enough time and space to go for head-on attack on Ties, enough to break their formation. X-wings even more so.

Comment: @NKCampbell Also, if first group (Y-wings) fails, there are two more groups of X-wings, faster and more maneuverable. There is no snowball's chance in hell that Ties would survive encounter with all of them, and remain in formation, like they did in movies .

Answer (score 2):

It's not explicitly stated, but from the way that the two supporting fighters follow the leader through the trench it is shown that they're there to act as a second set of rear shields for the leader.

Note that when Wedge gets his shields blown out, Luke commands him to leave the trench because he "can't do any more good back there".

Also, consider that the primary attackers were in fact the Y-wings. While the Y-wings were making their attack runs, the X-wings were above the trench mixing it up with the TIEs. Sending X-wings into the trench after Vader and his wingmen might have been a solution, but any stray shots would have flown past the TIEs towards friendly Y-wings.

Comment: Except this does not work, supporting Y-wings and X-wings get blown to bits in seconds, they don't buy much time. Fighters are fighters, they are not deflector shields. Stray shots are much less of concern then aimed shots by TIE fighters.

Comment: @rs.29 To be fair, they were blown apart in mere seconds by a Dark Lord of the Sith - I doubt very much that anyone could have for seen that Vader himself would come out to engage the attacking fighters. While the Audience is aware that Vader is chasing the plans because of a fear of vulnerability, the Rebels weren't aware of any of that - and were probably more aware of Tarkin's belief that the station was indestructible presumably because there had to be some kind of senate speech about Alderaan and the Death Star when the senate was dissolved.